# Changing label color on JS validation doesn't work and "bypasses" validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm doing a little excercise trying to write a simple form validation using JS.

I'm trying to make both input borders and labels red when validation fails. I'm having a little problem with labels turning red though.

If validation fails on firstName, everything works fine; label turns red and input border too. But wwhen failing validation on any other input, no alert is shown, no red borders/label appears and the page reloads, like if the form gets submitted and bypasses validation.

The weird thing is, if I remove the document.getElementById lines inside the ifs, validation works fine. I guess the problem is there, but why does it work just fine on the firstname label then?

Here's the code:

**HTML FORM:**

```
<div id="jsForm" class="jsForm">
                <div class="formContainer">
                    <form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return(validate());" method="">
                        <label for="firstname" id="firstNameLabel">First name<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
                        <label for="lastname" id="lastNameLabel">Last name<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
                        <label for="title" id="titleLabel">Title<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
                        <label for="emailAddress" id="emailAddressLabel">Email Address<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress"><br>
                        <label for="phone" id="phoneLabel">Phone<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br>
                        <label for="isClient" id="isClientLabel">Already a Client<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
                        <select name="isClient" id="isClient">
                            <option value disabled selected>--Please Select--</option>
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                        </select><br><br> 
                        <input type="submit" value="Contact Us">                      
                    </form>         
                </div>       
            </div>
```

**JS VALIDATION:**

```
function validate() {

    var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%\-\+]*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/
    var phoneRegex = /(\+|00)(297|93|244|1264|358|355|376|971|54|374|1684|1268|61|43|994|257|32|229|226|880|359|973|1242|387|590|375|501|1441|591|55|1246|673|975|267|236|1|61|41|56|86|225|237|243|242|682|57|269|238|506|53|5999|61|1345|357|420|49|253|1767|45|1809|1829|1849|213|593|20|291|212|34|372|251|358|679|500|33|298|691|241|44|995|44|233|350|224|590|220|245|240|30|1473|299|502|594|1671|592|852|504|385|509|36|62|44|91|246|353|98|964|354|972|39|1876|44|962|81|76|77|254|996|855|686|1869|82|383|965|856|961|231|218|1758|423|94|266|370|352|371|853|590|212|377|373|261|960|52|692|389|223|356|95|382|976|1670|258|222|1664|596|230|265|60|262|264|687|227|672|234|505|683|31|47|977|674|64|968|92|507|64|51|63|680|675|48|1787|1939|850|351|595|970|689|974|262|40|7|250|966|249|221|65|500|4779|677|232|503|378|252|508|381|211|239|597|421|386|46|268|1721|248|963|1649|235|228|66|992|690|993|670|676|1868|216|90|688|886|255|256|380|598|1|998|3906698|379|1784|58|1284|1340|84|678|681|685|967|27|260|263)(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{4,20}$/


    if( document.myForm.firstname.value == "" ) {   
        document.myForm.firstname.style.border = '1px solid';
        document.myForm.firstname.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
        document.getElementById("firstNameLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
        alert( "Please provide your first name!" );
        return false;
    }
    if( document.myForm.lastname.value == "" ) {
        document.myForm.lastname.style.border = '1px solid';
        document.myForm.lastname.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
        document.getElementById("lastNameLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
        alert( "Please provide your last name!" );
        return false;
    }
    if( document.myForm.title.value == "" ) {
        document.myForm.title.style.border = '1px solid';
        document.myForm.title.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
        document.getElementById("titleLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
        alert( "Please provide your title!" );
        return false;
    }
    if(document.myForm.emailAddress.value == "" || !emailRegex.test(document.myForm.emailAddress.value)) {
        document.myForm.emailAddress.style.border = '1px solid';
        document.myForm.emailAddress.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
        document.getElementById("emailAddressLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
        alert( "Please provide a valid email address!" );
        return false;
    }

    if( document.myForm.phone.value == "" || !phoneRegex.test(document.myForm.phone.value)) {
        document.myForm.phone.style.border = '1px solid';
        document.myForm.phone.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
        document.getElementById("phoneLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
        alert( "Please provide a valid phone number! (make sure you type your country code, e.g. +39)" );
        return false;
    }
    if( document.myForm.isClient.value == "" ) {
        document.myForm.isClient.style.border = '1px solid';
        document.myForm.isClient.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
        document.getElementById("isClientLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
        alert( "Please specify if you're already a client!" );
        return false;
    }
   
    return( true );
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I have run your code everything is working fine.

Comment: it actually works if I run that on JS fiddle... doesn't work on my locale though. Could it be something else that I have in the html page that makes things act weird?

Answer (score 0):

In the current situation, the form is always submitted when the submit button is clicked. I have developed a method as follows to prevent the form from being sent and to ensure that all controls are made. All checks are not performed if the method is called as follows:

```js
if(isValidFirstName() && isValidLastName() && ...){}
```

This is because the `&&` operator works from left to right and does not call other methods the first time it sees a `false` value. In the solution below, you will see that all values are submitted correctly. Because when the submit button is clicked, the previously incorrect and red marked entries do not turn black.

In addition, the reason you have developed in the solution is always the cause of the `validate()` your method is always `true` value returning.

```js
var emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%\-\+]*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/
var phoneRegex = /(\+|00)(297|93|244|1264|358|355|376|971|54|374|1684|1268|61|43|994|257|32|229|226|880|359|973|1242|387|590|375|501|1441|591|55|1246|673|975|267|236|1|61|41|56|86|225|237|243|242|682|57|269|238|506|53|5999|61|1345|357|420|49|253|1767|45|1809|1829|1849|213|593|20|291|212|34|372|251|358|679|500|33|298|691|241|44|995|44|233|350|224|590|220|245|240|30|1473|299|502|594|1671|592|852|504|385|509|36|62|44|91|246|353|98|964|354|972|39|1876|44|962|81|76|77|254|996|855|686|1869|82|383|965|856|961|231|218|1758|423|94|266|370|352|371|853|590|212|377|373|261|960|52|692|389|223|356|95|382|976|1670|258|222|1664|596|230|265|60|262|264|687|227|672|234|505|683|31|47|977|674|64|968|92|507|64|51|63|680|675|48|1787|1939|850|351|595|970|689|974|262|40|7|250|966|249|221|65|500|4779|677|232|503|378|252|508|381|211|239|597|421|386|46|268|1721|248|963|1649|235|228|66|992|690|993|670|676|1868|216|90|688|886|255|256|380|598|1|998|3906698|379|1784|58|1284|1340|84|678|681|685|967|27|260|263)(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{4,20}$/

function isValidFirstName(){
  if( document.myForm.firstname.value == 0){   
      document.myForm.firstname.style.border = '1px solid';
      document.myForm.firstname.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
      document.getElementById("firstNameLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
      alert( "Please provide your first name!" );
      return false;
  }
  else{
    document.myForm.firstname.style.borderColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("firstNameLabel").style.color = "black";
    return true;
  }
}

function isValidLastName(){
  if( document.myForm.lastname.value == "" ) {
      document.myForm.lastname.style.border = '1px solid';
      document.myForm.lastname.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
      document.getElementById("lastNameLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
      alert( "Please provide your last name!" );
      return false;
  }
  else{
      document.myForm.lastname.style.borderColor = 'black';
      document.getElementById("lastNameLabel").style.color = "black";
      return true;
  }
}

function isValidTitle(){
  if( document.myForm.title.value == "" ) {
      document.myForm.title.style.border = '1px solid';
      document.myForm.title.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
      document.getElementById("titleLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
      alert( "Please provide your title!" );
      return false;
  }
  else{
      document.myForm.title.style.borderColor = 'black';
      document.getElementById("titleLabel").style.color = "black";
      return true;
  }
}

function isValidEMail(){
  if(document.myForm.emailAddress.value == "" || !emailRegex.test(document.myForm.emailAddress.value)) {
      document.myForm.emailAddress.style.border = '1px solid';
      document.myForm.emailAddress.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
      document.getElementById("emailAddressLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
      alert( "Please provide a valid email address!" );
      return false;
  }
  else {
      document.myForm.emailAddress.style.borderColor = 'black';
      document.getElementById("emailAddressLabel").style.color = "black";
      return true;
  }
}

function isValidPhone(){
  if( document.myForm.phone.value == "" || !phoneRegex.test(document.myForm.phone.value)) {
      document.myForm.phone.style.border = '1px solid';
      document.myForm.phone.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
      document.getElementById("phoneLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
      alert( "Please provide a valid phone number! (make sure you type your country code, e.g. +39)" );
      return false;
  }
  else {
      document.myForm.phone.style.borderColor = 'black';
      document.getElementById("phoneLabel").style.color = "black";
      return true;
  }
}

function isValidClient(){
  if( document.myForm.isClient.value == "" ) {
      document.myForm.isClient.style.border = '1px solid';
      document.myForm.isClient.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
      document.getElementById("isClientLabel").style.color = "#ff0000";
      alert( "Please specify if you're already a client!" );
      return false;
  }
  else {
      document.myForm.isClient.style.borderColor = 'black';
      document.getElementById("isClientLabel").style.color = "black";
      return true;
  }
}

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.clear();
});

document.getElementById('firstname').addEventListener('input', isValidFirstName);
document.getElementById('lastname').addEventListener('input', isValidLastName);
document.getElementById('title').addEventListener('input', isValidTitle);
document.getElementById('emailAddress').addEventListener('input', isValidEMail);
document.getElementById('phoneLabel').addEventListener('input', isValidPhone);
document.getElementById('isClientLabel').addEventListener('onchange', isValidClient);

function validate() {
  let result = isValidFirstName();
  result &= isValidLastName();
  result &= isValidTitle();
  result &= isValidEMail();
  result &= isValidPhone();
  result &= isValidClient();
  
  if(result == 0){
    console.log(`Result: Unsuccessful`);
    return false;
  }
  
  console.log(`Result: Successfull`);
  return true;
}
```

```html
<button id="clear">Console Clear</button>

<div id="jsForm" class="jsForm">
    <div class="formContainer">
        <form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return(validate());" method="">
            <label for="firstname" id="firstNameLabel">First name<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
            <label for="lastname" id="lastNameLabel">Last name<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
            <label for="title" id="titleLabel">Title<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
            <label for="emailAddress" id="emailAddressLabel">Email Address<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress"><br>
            <label for="phone" id="phoneLabel">Phone<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br>
            <label for="isClient" id="isClientLabel">Already a Client<span class="boldStar">*</span></label><br>
            <select name="isClient" id="isClient">
                <option value disabled selected>--Please Select--</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select><br><br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Contact Us">                      
        </form>         
    </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that code but no alerts get fired and all borders and labels get red at once.... I'd need to fire alerts and make inputs and labels red one by one

Comment: If you inspect the code, you'd see that I've printed the warnings to the console. I edited the code, now you get a warning.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry, I didn't catch that. Is there a way to mark them red one by one and not all together?

Comment: I edited the code; I added event listener for <input> elements. The status is checked each time you enter a character in the <input> element; however, if the result is unsuccessful, a continuous warning window will alert.